# Is there any data on most common way to get to 10 VP in Settlers of Catan?

Tags: catan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Settlers of Catan Data](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2877/settlers-of-catan-data)

I sometimes track this for myself when I play online, and almost half the time when I win, I have Longest Road and either 3 Cities/2 Settlements or 2 Cities/4 Settlements.

I rarely win with Largest Army, but I have noticed from reading online that one of the more common winning combos is 3 cities, Largest Army, and either 2 VP or 1 VP and 1 settlement.

Is there any data on this sort of thing? Have you noticed and 1 or 2 combos coming up most frequently in games you play.

(Of course I realize there are many possibilities, strategy often changes mid-game, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen any collected data released, but the online play sites may have done so.